# Gitlab Environment configuration not working on production branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

I am trying to automate my CI/CD process using gitlab free edition(Gitlab Hosts it).
My use case is as follows -

1. I merge my code to master.
2. After an hour master merges to dev branch and deploys to the dev environment.
3. After 2 days dev merges to stage branch and deploys to stage environment and after a week stage merges to the production branch and deploys to the production environment.

I was playing with Gitlab environments and saw that you can just use environments to keep up a check on your deployments.
Here is gitlab-ci file -

```
stages:
  - lint
  - merge-sandbox
  - merge-staging
  - merge-production
  - build-container-sandbox
  - build-container-staging
  - build-container-production
  - build-container-master
  - deploy-sandbox
  - deploy
```

.........

```
deploy-production:
  stage: deploy
  image: xyz
  script:
      - runs deployment script

  environment:
    name: production
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  only:
    - production
```

I created an environment in gitlab called production but whenever I push the code to the production branch nothing shows up in the environment tab in the gitlab ui. I want the deploy job to be a manual job which would show up in the environment tab so that I don't have to go through the pipelines or jobs to look through the manual job to play. Simply like a play button that would show up in the environment for production deployment. Is there something wrong with my configuration here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pushing code to the production branch does not represent a successful deployment to the production environment.

You will see deployment for the production environment when the `deploy-production` job is executed.

Comment: I updated the question. I want the deploy-production job to be a manual job which would show up in the environment and from there I would be able to play that job. Right now it shows up in the pipelines and the jobs tab but going through it is a little tedious. Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: No, this is not possible.
In the Environments UI, you will be able to "Re-deploy" or "Rollback" a specific deployment but you will not be able to trigger a new deployment.

Comment: So there is no workaround click button option to do a manual deployment expect to go pipeline/jobs to deploy to production?

Comment: You can trigger it from Pipelines UI view, in a merge request, from the gitlab api.